# Syntax error using importing from sql file to sqlite manager

Tags: sql, sqlite

i have created my ERD using QSEEE superlite created an SQL file from it, but when i try to import it using the SQlite manager add on within fire fox i get the following message.

```
CREATE TABLE Item(

Item_id INTEGER NOT NULL,

Item_type   VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,

Item_Name   VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,

Item_Location   VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,

Item_Short_description  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

Item_long_Description   VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,

Item_Quantity   INTEGER NOT NULL,

Item_Price  FLOAT(6) NOT NULL,

Item_Delivery_Charge    FLOAT(6) NOT NULL,

Item_Image  VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,

fk1_Cat_id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
);
```

> [ near ")": syntax error ]
>   Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
>   Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

Does anyone have any ideas? it worked before but since i added a couple of extra tables this error shows up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the last comma after `fk1_Cat_id  INTEGER NOT NULL,`

Comment: That sorted that out cheers, but having another syntax error in regards to the constraints. Do you have any ideas? the message i am getting is : ALTER TABLE Item ADD CONSTRAINT fk1_Item_to_Category FOREIGN KEY(fk1_Cat_id) REFERENCES Category(Cat_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT; [ near "CONSTRAINT": syntax error ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

Comment: I found these diagrams from sq lite website very helpful, i have sorted all my syntax errors. This is the link if anyone is having similar problems http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html